# Django: Allow creation of model only within time period

Tags: python, django

In my web application I have the model `Event` and the model `Registration` (for an event).

Let's say the Event takes place on 31 January 2019 at 13:00. Now, I have to make sure that people can only register e.g. until the registration deadline that is defined in the Event model.

I'm using CBVs in Django and I'd like to ask WHERE I should put the check in the code so that people can only CREATE new registrations until the registration deadline. In my template I've this check already and the form is only displayed when it's before the deadline. However, I also have to make sure that people who know the form cannot POST to the specified site.

Is there a default way in Django to solve this problem? In which method should I check that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your simplest option would be within the function that is called when when rendering the view.

For example:

urls.py

```
`path('/somepath', views.RegistrationView)`
```

views.py

```
def RegistrationView(request):
    if datetime.datetime.now() > datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 31, 13):
        redirect('someOtherView')
```

A similar system can be used with Class Views